# Continuous map between metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Suppose $X,Y$ are metric spaces, let $A \subset X$ be a bounded subset of $X$ and $f: A \to Y$ to be a continuous bijection. Prove or disprove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Remark: If each closed subset of $A$ is compact then $f$ would map closed sets to closed sets, which would then imply the continuity of $f^{-1}$. Then, how do we prove/disprove that $f$ is a closed map?

Comment: spelling- bijection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with discrete metric and let $Y = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. All maps $X \to Y$ are continuous. No maps $Y \to X$ are continuous.

Comment: Constant maps $Y\longrightarrow X$ (and only them) are continuous.

Answer (score 3):

$X=\mathbb{R},A=[0,1),Y=S^1, f:x\mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a finite set with discrete topology $d(x,y)=1 \mathrm{if} x \neq y$ and$ =0 $ otherwise.  And $Y$ be the same set with trivial topology $d(x,y)=0$ $A=X$ and $f$ is the identity function, then $f$ is continuous but $f^{-1}$ is surely not continuous.